# How to add Admob at specific positions in RecyclerView PagedListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I am trying to show Admob banner ads at specific position in a RecyclerView which is a PagedListAdapter. With my current implementation I am able to add the views (that contains an ad) to the specific position but it replaces the actual ViewHolder with AdView.

The problem is with `getItemCount` and `getItemViewType` where I'm failing to provide the logic.

Can anyone show how it can be done?

I'm posting a simple case example.

```
public class MessageAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Message, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int ITEM_VIEW = R.layout.list_message;
    private static final int AD_VIEW = R.layout.list_ad;

    public MessageAdapter() {
        super(Message.DIFF_UTIL);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case ITEM_VIEW:
                view = inflater.inflate(ITEM_VIEW, parent, false);
                return new MessageViewHolder(view, mListener);
            case AD_VIEW:
                view = inflater.inflate(AD_VIEW, parent, false);
                return new AdViewHolder(view);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Holder type");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case ITEM_VIEW:
                Message message = getItem(position);
                ((MessageViewHolder) holder).bindTo(message.getId(), message.getTitle());
                break;
            case AD_VIEW:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position % 10 == 0) ? AD_VIEW : ITEM_VIEW;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return super.getItemCount();
    }


    static class AdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private AdView mAdView;

        AdViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
    //        mAdView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    //        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    //        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I wish I knew Paging Library :(

Comment: @UmangBurman How about: "How to add Views to specific positions in a RecyclerView"?

Comment: You mean to add RecyclerView item in RecyclerView at a specific position dynamically?

Comment: @UmangBurman Yes. Is my question confusing? Then I should edit it.

Comment: @pskink It would be helpful to know how can I do that, thanks, I'm asking as when I tried to add it with `add` method of `PagedList`, it gave me some errors at runtime.

Comment: Rajarshi, The question is not confusing, I just got confused with the first comment lol. Okay, if you want to add an item in the particular position of your RecyclerView, then just add that item in your ArrayList, and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() thing. Anyway you can add data at specific position in ArrayList. So that might work.

Comment: @pskink `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: @UmangBurman currently I am not able to do that, aren't there any other options?

Comment: ok so forget about it

Comment: Why are you not able to do that.? you can make the ArrayList static alternatively

Comment: @UmangBurman That's because I'm using `PagedList`, see the above replies to relate.

Comment: I wish I knew Paging Library :(  Lol. I'm Sorry I don't have any idea about it yet.

Comment: @Rajarshi admob can't allow you to put the banner inside the recyclerview. Please use the native ad for this. The native ad is created for this purpose only.

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal I think "can't allow" is not write. Abmob even have an working example at https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#samples_on_github. And Native Ad is still in beta and is not open to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but as I came across that post, there's a possibility that others do.

This may help you:

```
public static final int ADS_AFTER = 10;
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int s = super.getItemCount();
    int t  = s + (s / ADS_AFTER);
    if(s>0) t++; // +1 when list is not empty
    Log.e("☺☺☺ total is "+t+", real are "+s);
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the only problem you have is the getItemCount() because I think the `super.getItemCount();` return the number of message but you want to display add every 10 items so the total size is the number of messages plus the number of ads displayed.

You should tried something like this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return super.getItemCount() //Number of messages 
           + ((int) super.getItemCount() / 10) + 1 ; // Number of ads displayed the plus 1 is for the first element which will be an Ad
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what will be the logic on `getItemViewType`? Otherwise I'm getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` on `Message message = getItem(position);`

Comment: You need to calculate the number of ads in the list so for example you have index 34 as position do not forget to substract 4 for the ads displayed in the list (0,10,20,30) for getting the right message, it's only simple maths